# numpy covariance calculation (einsum potential?)

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write out a covariance calculation for the following example, and i know there has to be a better way than a for loop. I've looked into np.dot, np.einsum and i feel like np.einsum has the capability but i am just missing something for implementing it.

```py
import numpy as np

# this is mx3
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
# this is x3
mean = a.mean(axis=0)

# result should be 3x3
b = np.zeros((3,3))
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    b = b + (a[i]-mean).reshape(3,1) * (a[i]-mean)

b
array([[4.5, 4.5, 4.5],
       [4.5, 4.5, 4.5],
       [4.5, 4.5, 4.5]])
```

so this is fine for a 2 data point sample but for a m=large number this is super slow. There has to be a better way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Define `a1=a-mean` and explore `a1.T@a1`

Comment: Do you simply mean something like `a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]);
mu = np.mean(a, 0, keepdims=True);
print(np.einsum('ni, nj -> ij', a-mu, a-mu))`

Comment: that worked! can you explain that a bit as an answer and i can go ahead and accept it. I havent seen the "n" term in einsum. It looks like it takes the i-th term and multiplies is with the j-th term from the send entry with the n being row-wise process?

Comment: if i move the "n" to the second position like `in,jn->ij` then it looks like its a column process. Is that correct?

Comment: @hpaulj and ShlomiF thank you both for responding, these are great comments. Both concepts are new to me so thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [108]: a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
     ...: # this is x3
     ...: mean = a.mean(axis=0)
     ...: 
     ...: # result should be 3x3
     ...: b = np.zeros((3,3))
     ...: for i in range(a.shape[0]):
     ...:     b = b + (a[i]-mean).reshape(3,1) * (a[i]-mean)
     ...: 
In [109]: b
Out[109]: 
array([[4.5, 4.5, 4.5],
       [4.5, 4.5, 4.5],
       [4.5, 4.5, 4.5]])
In [110]: a.mean(axis=0)
Out[110]: array([2.5, 3.5, 4.5])
```

Since the mean is subtracted twice, lets define a new variable.  In this case the 2d and 1d dimensions broadcast, so we can simply:

```
In [111]: a1= a - a.mean(axis=0)
In [112]: a1
Out[112]: 
array([[-1.5, -1.5, -1.5],
       [ 1.5,  1.5,  1.5]])
```

The rest is a normal `dot` product:

```
In [113]: a1.T@a1
Out[113]: 
array([[4.5, 4.5, 4.5],
       [4.5, 4.5, 4.5],
       [4.5, 4.5, 4.5]])
```

`np.einsum` and `np.dot` can also do this matrix multiplication.